# Few questions related to MySQL Shell

Tags: mysql

In the MY SQL documentation [Instance Dump Utility, Schema Dump Utility, and Table Dump Utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-dump-instance-schema.html)

1. The compatibility option - strip_tablespaces
   Does it remove all references to tablespaces or only in the GRANT statement. Can you please provide an example for how this option makes change in the dump statement?
2. consistent

The documentation mentions that backup locks are released before the backup then how are consistent backups taken? START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT is mentioned. Does it take snapshots?
If yes, what is the memory requirement?

Thank you!

Comment: Your questions will have greater chances to be answered if you ask one question at a time and show your research so far, to avoid having people suggest something that you have already tried. For example, when you ran a dump with `strip_tablespaces`, what happened to tablespace references?

Answer (score 1):

1. It removes them from the GRANT / CREATE statements as per the doc you linked and also per this documentation: [Importing and Exporting Databases](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/mysql-database/doc/importing-and-exporting-databases.html)
2. Only the `global read lock` is released when the backups are started per the documentation you linked:

> When all threads have started their transactions, the instance is
> locked for backup and the global read lock is released.

In other words, the data is read safe but likely still holds other locks preventing the data or schema from being changed during the backup process (aka blocking transactions).

This website goes into good detail on global locks and specifically read locks in MySQL which is relevant to this question: [Deep Understanding of MySQL Global Lock and Table Lock](https://developpaper.com/deep-understanding-of-mysql-global-lock-and-table-lock/)

Specifically this part mentions what type of statements are locked:

> A global lock is to lock the entire database instance. MySQL provides
> a way to add a global read lock. The command isFlush tables with read
> lock (FTWRL)。
>
> When you need to make the whole library read-only, you can use this
> command, and then the following statements of other threads will be
> blocked: data update statements (data addition and deletion), data
> definition statements (including table building, table structure
> modification, etc.) and submission statements for updating class
> transactions.

So yes, technically the data is a snapshot in time because no other transactions are allowed to change the data or schema during the backups. The amount of memory needed is going to be dependent on the amount of data being backed up.

Comment: On reading this documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-instance-for-backup.html, seems like DML operations are permitted. "while preventing operations that could result in an inconsistent snapshot". I did not get this part. How does it decide? Either all DML operations must be blocked or none. I did not get how it decides.

Comment: If the other locks are not released during the backup, why is the need to maintain snapshots? It is not practical to maintain locks to prevent updation of data. If the data is locked during backup, how will the operations occur during the period